# Java does something for 15 seconds and then something else 5 sec after

Tags: java, timer

So I wanted to implement a timer that would allow me to draw a red square every 15 seconds and then after it was there for 5 seconds make the square disappear from the canvas. It is a trap in the game that I want to implement, but am not sure how the timer would work.

I figured I need 2 timers one for the appearing, and the second for disappearing(?) but am not sure how to sync them so that the square appears and stays at a position of the canvas for 5 seconds in 15 second periods either. (it might even be better to have it in a random 15-20 second increment of time). It's important that this item disappears after I turn the canvas from say red to white.

How does calling a timer in a function work? Do I need a new class for this? Is an instance variable enough?

Comment: You could use a single timer, but, the engine would know when the next trap should be shown (or when it was last displayed) and knows when it should be hidden

Comment: The point is, you could have multiple "events" which are managed by a single Timer. Remember, more threads/timers doesn't equal better performance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're missing some important details (like which framework you're using), but the basic idea would be...

- Have a single "main loop" which is responsible for updating the state of the game and scheduling updates to the UI
- Have a `List` of "event"s which are designed to be triggered at a given point in time, have the "main loop" check these events (maybe ordered in time order to make it more efficient to iterate) and trigger the ones which need to be triggered based on the current time and the time of the event (this would obviously remove the event from the `List`)

Events could create new events, so for example, when your trap door event is triggered it could trigger a "remove" event for 5 seconds in the future.  Equally, when the remove event is triggered, if could trigger a new "trap door" event

This way, you could have any number of trap doors appearing at random intervals.

Remember, more thread's/timer doesn't equate to better performance and would also increase the overall complexity of your problem, as you'd need to put in a series of checks to ensure everything stayed on sync

Comment: Would any one like to point out the reason for the downvote? In what ways does it not answer the ops question? In what ways could it be improved? Apparently we're not suppose to try and help people. Since you've chosen not to downvote the question or the the other answers I can only assume you're been an ass

Answer (score 1):

Being a java graphic application I would just create instances of SwingWorker and fire it when needed.  Every SwingWorker would start with an appropriate sleep call (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html).  Have a look at the Swing documentation in order to create proper SwingWorkers that run in the background, waiting and doing later the task you need (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

Comment: Or a Swing Timer since it's safe to interact with EDT from within

Comment: That's even better, I didn't know that one! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new thread making all the timer work.

But this segment into the place the timer is needed:

```
new Thread(new Runnable()) {
@override
public void run() {
   while(true) {

     // do the drawing stuff

     try {
        sleep(5000); // make the thread wait 5000 microsecs = 5s
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}

     // do deleting stuff

     try {
        sleep(15000); 
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
   }
```

This starts a new thread repeatedly doing the create-, wait-, delete- and wait-process.

Comment: I am not totally confident how this would work, but I would add for sure that in the commented section they should consider using `invokeLater` in order to alter the Canvas in a threadsafe manner (http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/invokeandwait-invokelater-swing-example.html)

Comment: Just remember, most gui frameworks aren't great safe, and this could cause great synchronisation issues

Comment: @MadProgrammer that's right... I forgot that Swing is not thread-safe. Though it works fine if you implement your own `Runnable` and pass it to `invokeLater()`